# cakephp how to check variable content and all function included?

Tags: cakephp

sorry i was new here so this problem maybe simple.

anyone knows how to check variable content?

like xx($a);

then page shows all relate information about $a. Is CakePHP allowed to do that?

i setup a kit on my cakephp

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for either [var_dump()](http://nz1.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) or [print_r()](http://nz1.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)

Comment: p.s. echo '<pre>'; before you call it, and exit; after you call it to get nice output

Answer (score 0):

You can use **PHP built-in functions** like

- [var_dump()](http://nz1.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) - displays structured information about variable
- [print_r()](http://nz1.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) - the same, but preformatted with some differences
- [get_defined_vars()](http://nz1.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php) - returns array with all defined variables

Or use **true CakePHP-way**

- [Debugger::dump()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/debugging.html#Debugger%3a%3adump) - It will print out all properties and methods (if any) of the supplied variable

For more convenience you may use [CakePHP Debug Kit](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit) plugin, which provides nice toolbar and some useful tools for your purpose.